# how to simulate websocket request and capture the streaming data using python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, websocket

I want to scrape real-time data sent thru websocket, using Chrome I can see the websocket request and response and data it sending in, but how do I scrape the data using python and **without using Selenium**? Tested Selenium it working but too slow, can I stream websocket data **without using Selenium** and not loading the entire web?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with `BeautifulSoup` library ?

Comment: Hi, yes tried BeautifulSoup but there's no way to get the websocket since the BS only download the html.

Comment: Can u provide an url and some context ? ty